# Show only hours and minutes without date

Tags: datetime, datediff

I have a column that shows the date and time (DD/MM/YY HH:mm) but I just need hours and minutes.

I have tried the short way of concatenation:

concat(date_part('hour', start_time),':',date_part('minute', start_time)) AS "Start time"

but I get only one number in the minutes, without 0 such as "21.3" instead of "21.30"

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using postgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL then this query will work:

```
concat(TO_CHAR(start_time,'HH'),':',TO_CHAR(start_time,'MM')) AS "Start time"
```